# How to use AWS Route 53 as the DNS service for a domain name without transferring that domain from the original registrar to Route 53 service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain name registered at a registrar other than **AWS Route 53**. To be precise, at namecheap.com.

Now, I want to use some of the Amazon AWS services and I find it's better to use AWS Route 53 as the DNS service for my domain. But I don't want to transfer my domain name from the original registrar to AWS Route 53.

When I create a Hosted Zone in Route 53, I get 4 values for the Nameservers which I can use with my domain name at my domain registrar website.

**My question:** Is using those Nameservers with my domain name at my domain registrar website automatically makes AWS Route 53 to be my DNS service for that domain?

Answer (score 5):

That's correct. The Nameserver records are list of IP addresses for the servers that store the mapping of your domain name to your backend IP Address. or your cloudfront domain (in case you are using cloudfront). Once you register the nameserver records you get from Route53 hosted zone with your domain name registrar , you can use Route53 similar to how you'd use it had you purchased the domain from AWS itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah thats correct. Adding the 4 NS records at your registrar will basically make route53 leading for all your DNS entries in that domain.